# Unable to call a local function on ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning to develop a Rest API using NodeJs with Express JS. I build a controller to do my stuff inside it. I want to call a local function inside the controller but it is not working. I always get **not defined** error.

Hear is my Controller,

```
const db = require('../config/db');

class TransactionController {

    constructor(){
    }
    
    generateCustomerTransaction(req, res) {

        const program_id = req.params.program_id;

        const customerList = getCustomerList(program_id); //error here

        //Do some business logics

        return res.json(result);
    };


    getCustomerList(program_id) {
       //Do some query to get a list of result
       return results;
    }
}

module.exports = SeatExcelController;
```

Everything seems simple like others languages but I get

**ReferenceError: getCustomerList is not defined**

I have no idea how to simply call a local function.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: While exporting you are using a wrong class name. Use `TransactionController` instead.

Comment: Change `const customerList = getCustomerList(program_id);` to `const customerList = this.getCustomerList(program_id);`.  In Javascript, you must reference the object when calling a method.  If the object you wish to reference is the object you are currently in a method for, then you use `this` as the object reference.  In your example, you will also have to make sure that `generateCustomerTransaction()` is called in a way that will have an appropriate value for `this`.  You don't show where that is called for us to advise on that part of it.

Comment: I note that none of the methods you show reference any instance data so perhaps instance methods on a class are not the appropriate tool here.  Perhaps they should be static methods on the class or just plain functions.

Comment: Also, `getCustomerList()` is NOT a local function.  It's a method defined on your class.  It is scoped such that it's generally only available in the context of an instance of that class.  So, you would typically use an instance of the class in order to then reference that method on that instance.  So, please don't think these are just normal functions that have normal function scope.  They are not.  You could define them as normal functions if you want to use them that way.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access your function that way it needs to be defined on the package scope outside the class as in:

```js
const db = require('../config/db');

const getCustomerList(program_id) = () => {
   // Do some query to get a list of result
   return results;
}

class TransactionController {
    
    generateCustomerTransaction(req, res) {
        const program_id = req.params.program_id;
        const customerList = getCustomerList(program_id); //error here
        //Do some business logics
        return res.json(result);
    };
}

module.exports = SeatExcelController;
```

Or call your function with `this` before the call as in:

```js
const db = require('../config/db');

class TransactionController {
    
    generateCustomerTransaction(req, res) {
        const program_id = req.params.program_id;
        const customerList = this.getCustomerList(program_id); //error here
        //Do some business logics
        return res.json(result);
    };

    function getCustomerList(program_id) {
        // Do some query to get a list of result
        return results;
    }
}

module.exports = SeatExcelController;
```

I would go for the first option if the function doesn't need to access any class variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make this a static function if it is not related to the class:

```
static getCustomerList(program_id) {
   //Do some query to get a list of result
   return results;
}
```

and call the function like this:

```
TransactionController.getCustomerList(program_id)
```

or just call the function using the this keyword. Because the way you code it now, the function is belonging to your class and class dependent.
: `this.getCustomerList(program_id)`